# firebase custom auth system : no provider id for custom token authentication, after sign in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the firebase custom auth token system to add LinkedIn as auth provider. I have setup the Google Functions to receive the LinkedIn Access token from android over http trigger, then query LinkedIn Api to get details of user and create a user in firebase with uid `"linkedin:$linkedin-user-id"`

But now the problem is the firebase is not putting any provider id for custom auth like it do for federated providers in `FirebaseUser.getproviders()`. I need this information since my app also supports EmailAuth, GoogleAuth and FacebookAuth. Based on the provider I need to perform provider specific functions.

Checking providers list for empty will only work if only LinkedIn is associated with user, if user has multiple accounts this check will fail.

Is there any solution to this scenario? Firebase has probably its own reason not to include provider id for custom, but I need to some how identify the linkedin provider used for login

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if-elseif-else statement like this:

```
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    for (UserInfo userInfo : firebaseUser.getProviderData()) {
        if (userInfo.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User is signed in with Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (userInfo.getProviderId().equals("google.com")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are signed in Google!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are signed in LinkedIn!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does provider data gives info only about the provider used to login or every provider associated with the current user ?

Comment: As you can see in the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) it does. There are also other useful methods.

Comment: Yes, but using different way. I have to store a shared preferences to store type of login used. then I have to listen for the database node which is basically a key-value pair of uid:linkedin-id. Putting user defined uid from firebase function was not a good option

Comment: so my workaround is to use shared preferences during login.

Comment: Did my answer helped you in any way?